# Flutter: How to wrap text inside a given width?

Tags: flutter, dart, text, flutter-layout

What I am trying to achieve is like how we see text messages like the image below. But when I put a long text I am getting the screen overflow error. I tried using `softwrap: true` with all the `overflow: TextOverflow.xxxx` options, but doesn't seem to do what I am looking for. For reference I put my code here.

```
Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                    child: Container(
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.all(5),
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            'Add a very long text the goes a few lines',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                            softWrap: true,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            '3:08',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black38),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `Text` with `Flexible` widget to fix the overflow.

```dart
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
  child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Flexible(
          child: Text(
            'Add a very long text the goes a few lines',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
            softWrap: true,
            overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          '3:08',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black38),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: If you are looking for conversation row handling, [this](https://github.com/yeasin50/Flutter-Video-Calling-App/blob/master/lib/screens/chat_screen/components/message_box.dart) will give you some idea. Also you can find packages on pub for this

Comment: could you suggest me a package?

Comment: like using [flutter_chat_ui](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_chat_ui) search for chat ui

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the text around an [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget. The text is going to wrap inside the available width.

Take a look at the screenshots below and the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=ab5a24c8e43dbdee90398645f4873573).

| Thinner | Regular | Wider |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

Here's the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: const [
              Expanded(
                child: Text(
                  'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus egestas dui elit, et porttitor lorem sodales ut. Maecenas quis lacinia arcu, a ultricies enim.',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                  softWrap: true,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                '3:08',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: Colors.black38),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```